# Show Delete Button in Tableview in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I added a button as subview in TableViewCell. When this button pressed, I need to show the Delete Button(right side) same as when we swipe the row.
I don't want to show small delete button(left side).
I need to implement same function when we press small delete button(left side), Big delete button display(right side).

**my code**

```
-(IBAction)act_press
{
[tblArticles setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //do delete stuff
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: have your tried to add your own button to each row, and handle its event as deleting the current row?

Comment: I guess you are using custom cells, so just add the button to right side or the cell as custom content, and handle the touch-up-inside event.

Comment: @holex, but I want to show the default Delete Button.

Comment: you just cannot show the default delete button as you'd like to show. the default delete button is controlled by iOS not by your app.

Comment: sure thing. how do you know about how other apps work behind the scene? be honest, you don't...

Comment: sorry for saying that but you are a bit hothead here and your _assupmtion_ is incorrect – those are custom contents only. you __cannot__ do such thing with the default delete button.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set UITableViewCell style for that indexPath

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state{
    [super willTransitionToState:state];
    if ((state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) == UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) {
        for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
            if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl"]) {
                   // remove or hide the left small view
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: quoted from OP: _"I don't want to show small delete button(left side)"_.

Comment: get the cell for selected indexPath and remove your button from view! or hide for now

Comment: I am not given downward.

Comment: it's ok, see my updated code. get your button object and make it hidden for current indexPath!

Comment: but it is the same as previous. this button is not left side delete button.